# Shipping information from SQUARE CONNECT

Tags: square-connect

I have been tasked to develop a way to create shipping labels for items to be shipped from the Square Market.

Is there a way to download or access the shipping data entered by the buyers during the order process?

I would like to use the Square Connect API.

The information is available on the "Order Confirmation" page but that is not is JSON form.

Is this going to be available at some time in the future through the Square Connect API?

Answer (score 0):

Order management, including accessing shipping addresses for Square Market orders, is currently not possible with the Square Connect API. All available functionality is described in the [documentation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api).

However, we are actively developing the API, and I will pass this feedback along to the engineering team.